# Dynamic add columns in a tablix in reporting service

Tags: c#, vb.net, dynamic, service, reporting

I'm having a big trouble in my work...
I need to create a report in reporting service on visual studio 2012. The problem is that the report have dynamic columns that depend for example on the number of feedbacks a user have.

I already tried doing it with tablix and matrix using column groups with no success, but i did not tried using a custom code for the report...

Details: i'm building the dataset manually, all the rows must be grouped.

Any ideas how to do it? Anybody know if the custom code for the report can resolve my problem?

PS. sry about my english :P

Comment: Make your tablix with all possible columns then go to the tablix property and use the visibility to make some conditions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, summing it up:

It seens to be impossible using only the reporting server native tools.

The only solution i found was to dynamically change the rdlc, which is a xml. This way you can add and remove columns and row groups removing the nodes from the xml, hard, but it works...

Thanks for the help anyway!